# What does "errors" of Twitter API's error response mean

Tags: twitter, oauth, asp.net-web-api

Twitter API's error response is something like this.

`{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}`

But I don't know why the key name (`errors`) is plural form and the value is an array.
I have never seen multiple errors are listed on this array. 
Are there any case? If it be, tell me how you send a request.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/error-codes-responses

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error above usually means the user/object you called the API on does not exist. Occasionally, it's a transient error but mostly it's because the object has been deleted.

As for seeing "errors", I've seen it in quite a few places. Twitter error handling seems to be all over the map. Twitter usually, not always, returns JSON in content in error cases , which provides more data.

Copy-pasting part of python code (in progress) dealing with some "errors". Please ignore the RR_XXX since those are mappings to internal error codes for my app.

```
status = resp['status']
if not status == '200':
    errJson = json.loads(content) //Handle "ValueError" with try-except

    if 'error' in errJson:
        # HTTP-401: {"request":"...", "error":"Not authorized"}
        err_code = RR_TWITERR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
    elif 'errors' in errJson:
        errors = errJson['errors']                   
        sub_code = errors[0]['code']                
        if sub_code == 88:
            # HTTP-429: {"errors":[{"message":"Rate limit exceeded","code":88}]}
            err_code = RR_TWITERR_RATELIMIT_EXCEEDED                    
        elif sub_code == 130:
            # HTTP-503: {"errors":[{"message":"Over capacity","code":130}]}                    
            err_code = RR_TWITERR_OVER_CAPACITY
        **elif sub_code == 34:
            # HTTP-404: {"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}**                    
            err_code = RR_TWITERR_NOT_FOUND
        elif sub_code == 32:                    
            # HTTP-401:[{u'message': u'Could not authenticate you', u'code': 32}]
            err_code = RR_TWITERR_NOT_AUTHENTICATED            
        elif sub_code == 63:
            # HTTP 403:{"errors":[{"code":63,"message":"User has been suspended."}]}
            err_code = RR_TWITERR_USER_SUSPENDED
        elif sub_code == 131:
            # HTTP-500:{"errors":[{"message":"Internal error","code":131}]}
            err_code = RR_TWITERR_INTERNAL_ERROR
        else:
            err_code = RR_TWITERR_UNKNOWN
    else:
        err_code = RR_TWITERR_UNKNOWN

    return err_code
```

Comment: I agree, there error responses vary a bit - we do something similar, actually consolidating the two possibilities into one. I think they do "errors" for future proofing, you could have a 'api-threshold limit' and an 'over 140' error at the same time - but I've never seen it. It's more likely someone just decided this when they were coding it up...